# ASP.NET Core tag helper for conditionally adding a class to an element

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In Asp.Net MVC we can add class conditionally as following code:

```
<div class="choice @(Model.Active?"active":"")">
</div>
```

How can do this by using tagHelper and by remove else part in condition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ability to add a conditional css class by following tagHelper provides.
this code like AnchorTagHelper asp-route-* for add route values acts.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = ClassPrefix + "*")]
public class ConditionClassTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string ClassPrefix = "condition-class-";

    [HtmlAttributeName("class")]
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<string, bool> _classValues;

    [HtmlAttributeName("", DictionaryAttributePrefix = ClassPrefix)]
    public IDictionary<string, bool> ClassValues
    {
        get {
            return _classValues ?? (_classValues = 
                new Dictionary<string, bool>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
        set{ _classValues = value; }
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var items = _classValues.Where(e => e.Value).Select(e=>e.Key).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CssClass))
        {
            items.Insert(0, CssClass);
        }

        if (items.Any())
        {
            var classes = string.Join(" ", items.ToArray());
            output.Attributes.Add("class", classes);
        }
    }
}
```

in _ViewImports.cshtml add reference to taghelper as following

```
@addTagHelper "*, WebApplication3"
```

Use tagHelper in View:

```
<div condition-class-active="Model.Active" condition-class-show="Model.Display">
</div>
```

result for Active = true and Display = true is:

```
<div class="active show">
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to use suffixes, not only prefixes? say `class-*-if`?

Comment: @Serge From the inline documentation, the * may only appear at the end. So it's probably not possible today.

Comment: When I use the above code with the example it renders `<div condition-class-active="condition-class-active"></div>`

Comment: @MohammadAkbari please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251583/asp-net-core-conditional-class-tag-helper

Comment: @mheptinstall: You have a spelling mistake. You should use condition-class-active instead of conditional-class-active

Answer (score 2):

There's no default way to do what you're asking. You would have to write a TagHelper that did that logic for you. Aka

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "asp-active")]
public class FooTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperOutput output, TagHelperContext context)
    {
        if (Active)
        {
            // Merge your active class attribute onto "output"'s attributes.
        }
    }
}
```

And then the HTML would look like:

```
<div class="choice" asp-active="Model.Active"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function for adding classes, see `TagHelperOutputExtensions.AddClass`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.taghelperoutputextensions.addclass

```cs
public class SomeHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        base.Process(context, output);
        // Wrap this in some condition.
        output.AddClass("myclass", HtmlEncoder.Default);
    }
}
```