# Track the current active page, or how to get controller and action names in a view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I am new in ASP.NET Core. I have a navigation menu and I would like to track the active item.
My idea is to use the action and controller names as navigation keys:

[image]

the problem is I don't know how to obtain the action and controller name in the _Layout.cshtml view...

I have tried the `ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName` but it renders something like this *`MyApp.Controllers.RecordsController.Index (MyApp)`*

I'd rather prefer to obtain something like this:

```
<script>$("li#@(Controller.Name)-@(Action.Name)")).addClass("active");</script>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use

```
var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];

<script>
$("li#@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"])-@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"])")).addClass("active");
</script>
```

PS:
Use ToLower() if required

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower();
```

Also you can activate your menu by style block

```
<style>
li#@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"])-@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]) {
//add some style
}
</style>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a silly question but I am converting some code to .NET Core and converting Controller/Action code to use Razor pages instead. I've come across some generic code which uses the ViewContext.RouteData to pull out the action name. To invoke my Razor page action, what do I pass to the 'Action' parameter on the @Html.ActionLink extension?

Answer (score 12):

With dot net core 2.0 for razor pages you could use like this

```
var rv = ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
string page = $"{rv["page"]}".ToLowerInvariant();
```

On the tags

```
<li class="@(page == "/index" ?  "active" : "")"><a asp-page="/Index" >Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add something small that has perhaps been overlooked...
Just add some embedded code in the layouts page at the top, before the HTML begins...

```
@{
    var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
    var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];
}
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory...
Then call the variables' values from anywhere within your code just as they are, like the way I did as shown below:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
<h3>@controller | @action</h3>
</div>
```

I found this method to be much simpler and hassle-free than aforementioned methods.
Cheerio ;)

Comment: The approach here makes it very easy to add the "active" class to the current page's `nav-item`.

Comment: Great answer. Helped me fix a view issue in dotnet 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this server side if you combine [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337101/asp-net-core-tag-helper-for-conditionally-add-class-to-an-element) with the following.

Somewhere in your view.

```
@{
    var rv = ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
    var id = $"{rv["Controller"]}-{rv["Action"]}".ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

On each `<li>`.

```
<li class-conditional-active="@(id == "records-index")">...</li>
```

Comment: there is no such thing as ControllerName and ActionName... in the ActionDescriptor... I would use it

Comment: You're right. I was inspecting in VSCode and it was showing up properties are there but not public. @itikhomi's answer is correct. I would still question the use of JavaScript to do this.

Comment: @benembery, set active menu style in script/style block is better than many if's\switch in server code. Can you do it in backend without if\switch?

Comment: what is your "class-conditional-active", why do you invent things that does not exist?

Comment: @itikhomi it depends, i.e. on the importance/reliance on JS, not something I would recommend. Given the current code sample, it's not possible without switch/if's

Comment: @serge see linked answer's code sample. It may be worth considering using a `ViewComponent` that would allow you to handle this effectively.