# Extension method to get a controller name without suffix

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I don't want to repeat the following

```
nameof(HomeController).Replace(nameof(Controller), string.Empty)
```

everytime I need to supply controller name without suffix "Controller".

Is there any elegant way to simplify? I attempted to create an extension method as follows but I don't know how to get the instance of the controller in question from a cshtml view.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static string BareName(this Controller controller)
        {
            return nameof(controller.GetType).Replace(nameof(Controller), string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to invoke the following, for example, in view page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("something", nameof(HomeController.someaction), nameof(HomeController).Replace(nameof(Controller), string.Empty))
```

Comment: Can't you invoke `this.BareName()` in your controller's method and add the returned value to the `ViewBag` passed down to te cshtml view?

Comment: @PietroMartinelli: But using `ViewBag` is error prone.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479244/asp-net-core-track-the-current-active-page-or-how-to-get-controller-and-action?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a separate extension method on `ActionContext` which resolves the controller name from the `ActionDescriptor`.

```
public static string GetControllerName(this ActionContext actionContext)
{
    return (actionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor)?.ControllerName;
}
```

You don't need to trim the "Controller" part from the string in this case. Call it in your view like this:

```cs
var controllerName = ViewContext.GetControllerName();
```

Comment: This is a good answer for getting the *current* controller name. However, the OP gives the impression from his question that they want to get the name for any arbitrary controller, since using `Html.ActionLink` is mentioned. You don't even need to pass the controller param, if the controller is the same as what you're currently on.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you want the name of the controller which is not currently handling the request, you want something like this:

```
public static string BareName<T>() where T: Controller
{
    return typeof(T).Name.Replace(nameof(Controller), string.Empty);
}
```

You can then use it like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("something", nameof(HomeController.someaction), Utilities.BareName<HomeController>())
```

I'm still not sure why Microsoft hasn't put this as part of the ASP.NET Core core package...

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a view, just use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]`.

**UPDATE (based on edited question)**

So, yeah, it wasn't clear before what you were actually trying to achieve. Basically, you want to be able to specify the controller/action params of methods like `Html.Action` without using hard-coded strings. As far as extension methods go, your best bet is an `IHtmlHelper` extension like:

```
public static class IHtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string GetControllerName<TController>(this IHtmlHelper helper)
        where TController : Controller
    {
        return typeof(TController).GetName().Replace("Controller", "");
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like:

```
Html.GetControllerName<HomeController>()
```

However, this still feels clunky to me. Honestly, if you're looking to avoid hard-coding things, I'd recommend naming your routes and using a static class to house the names:

```
public static class RouteNames
{
    public const string Home = "Home";
}
```

Then:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("", Name = RouteNames.Home)]
    public IActionResult Index() => View();
}
```

And then finally:

```
@Html.RouteLink(RouteNames.Home, RouteNames.Home)
```

Or via tag helper:

```
<a asp-route="@RouteNames.Home">@RouteNames.Home</a>
```

Comment: That's not hard coding. "controller" is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get controller, action or area name inside a view or controller, here are some options:

you just need a reference to an `ViewContext` or `HttpContext` or `IHtmlHelper` object:

```
////////////////////////////////
// with an IHtmlHelper object //
////////////////////////////////
var request = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request;
var controllerName = request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
var actionName = request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
// if area exists
var areaName = request.RouteValues["area"].ToString();

//////////////////////////////////
// with an `ViewContext` object //
//////////////////////////////////
var controllerName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
// if area exists
var areaName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString();
```

So an extension method for IHtmlHelper could be as follows:

```
public static class IHtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string GetControllerName(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) =>
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]string controller)
{ 
    //controller will be Controller name without suffix "Controller".
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var controllerName = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName.Replace(nameof(Controller), string.Empty);
```