# How to create bread crumb according to controller and action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I want to create breadcrumb in partial view . I want controller name and action method name in bredcrumb, how do i create it in partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];

<script>
    $("li#@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"])/ 
    @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"])")).addClass("active");
</script>
```

This will get you the current controller name and its view name you are in.

Reference from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479611/6029001